# Mbed OS exported project does not build on System Workbench

Tags: ide, stm32, mbed

I'm starting to develop on MBED OS. I want to work offline.

I exported the example "blinky" application to System Workbench IDE. The exported project does not build.
The compilation errors are pretty basic (missing include paths):

```
arm-none-eabi-gcc -mcpu=cortex-m4 -mthumb -mfloat-abi=softfp -mfpu=fpv4-sp-d16 -std=c99 '-DDEVICE_CRC=1' '-DDEVICE_SPI=1' '-DDEVICE_I2C=1' '-D__MBED__=1' '-DDEVICE_I2CSLAVE=1' '-D__FPU_PRESENT=1' '-DDEVICE_PORTOUT=1' -DUSBHOST_OTHER '-DDEVICE_PORTINOUT=1' -DTARGET_RTOS_M4_M7 '-DDEVICE_RTC=1' '-DDEVICE_SERIAL_ASYNCH=1' -D__CMSIS_RTOS '-DDEVICE_ANALOGOUT=1' -DTOOLCHAIN_GCC '-DDEVICE_I2C_ASYNCH=1' -DTARGET_STM32L476xG -DTARGET_CORTEX_M -DTARGET_LIKE_CORTEX_M4 -DTARGET_STM32L476RG -DTARGET_M4 -DTARGET_STM32L4 '-DDEVICE_SPI_ASYNCH=1' '-DDEVICE_LPTICKER=1' '-DDEVICE_PWMOUT=1' '-DDEVICE_INTERRUPTIN=1' -DTARGET_CORTEX -DTARGET_NUCLEO_L476RG '-DTRANSACTION_QUEUE_SIZE_SPI=2' -D__CORTEX_M4 '-DDEVICE_USTICKER=1' '-DDEVICE_STDIO_MESSAGES=1' -DTARGET_FF_MORPHO -DTARGET_FAMILY_STM32 -DTARGET_FF_ARDUINO '-DDEVICE_PORTIN=1' -DTARGET_RELEASE -DTWO_RAM_REGIONS -DTARGET_STM '-DDEVICE_SERIAL_FC=1' '-DMBED_BUILD_TIMESTAMP=1540971180.81' '-DDEVICE_TRNG=1' -DTARGET_LIKE_MBED -D__MBED_CMSIS_RTOS_CM '-DDEVICE_SLEEP=1' -DTOOLCHAIN_GCC_ARM '-DDEVICE_CAN=1' '-DDEVICE_SPISLAVE=1' '-DDEVICE_ANALOGIN=1' '-DDEVICE_SERIAL=1' '-DDEVICE_FLASH=1' -DARM_MATH_CM4 -DMBED_DEBUG '-DMBED_TRAP_ERRORS_ENABLED=1' -DMBED_DEBUG '-DMBED_TRAP_ERRORS_ENABLED=1' -DNDEBUG -DNDEBUG  -includeC:/mbed-os-example-blinky2_sw4stm32_nucleo_l476rg/mbed-os-example-blinky2/mbed_config.h -O2 -funsigned-char -fno-delete-null-pointer-checks -fomit-frame-pointer -fmessage-length=0 -fno-builtin -g3 -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-missing-field-initializers -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -c -MMD -MP -MF"mbed-os/features/storage/FEATURE_STORAGE/cfstore/source/configuration_store.d" -MT"mbed-os/features/storage/FEATURE_STORAGE/cfstore/source/configuration_store.o" -o "mbed-os/features/storage/FEATURE_STORAGE/cfstore/source/configuration_store.o" "../mbed-os/features/storage/FEATURE_STORAGE/cfstore/source/configuration_store.c" @"mbed-os/features/storage/FEATURE_STORAGE/cfstore/source/includes.args"
../mbed-os/features/storage/FEATURE_STORAGE/flash-journal/flash-journal-strategy-sequential/strategy.c:18:10: fatal error: flash-journal-strategy-sequential/flash_journal_crc.h: No such file or directory
```

I have 2 questions:

- it looks like either I am missing something or the maturity of the exporting functionality is pretty low. What is your feedback on this ?
- I tried to add the include paths myself in the Project Settings but it doesn't work. And I noticed that the gcc command line seems to ignore the project settings and instead use the include.args file. Only problem is the latter file does not exist. I guess it should be generated by System Workbench when it generates the Makefiles ?

PS: the exported project for IAR builds fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> What is your feedback on this ?

My feedback is that the maturity of the exporting function depends on the exporter. As you mentioned the IAR exporter produced a correct project file.

> I guess it should be generated by System Workbench when it generates the Makefiles ?

That is my impression as well. Based on the error message, `arm-none-eabi-gcc` is not failing to find the `includes.args` file and it's looking in a path that is one level above where it was invoked. This implies that `arm-none-eabi-gcc` was invoked within a directory that itself does not contain the source. Instead, the Makefile is probably setup to run the compiler from within the build directory. Perhaps `mbed-os/features/storage/FEATURE_STORAGE/cfstore/source/includes.args` may be found in your build directory.

It seems that `../mbed-os/features/storage/FEATURE_STORAGE/flash-journal/` or `mbed-os/features/storage/FEATURE_STORAGE/flash-journal/` is missing from the include paths. It may resolve the immediate issue to add that path to the include paths.

---

Now for some more general advice:

> I want to work offline.

Have you tried Mbed-CLI?

When did you run the export from the online compiler?
We fix bugs in the online compiler all of the time, and you may have encountered something that we fixed in the mean time.

Exporting from Mbed CLI is in general simpler and how contributors test their exporter, so it may work better.

Comment: Thank you and sorry for the delay. To answer your questions, I tried the online compiler last week. I didn't try MBed CLI because I wanted a full feature IDE.

Comment: Perhaps you could use Mbed CLI as the build command in a full feature IDE. I think os.mbed.com has instructions on setting up Eclipse for example. Generally, you would change the build command from `make` to `mbed compile ...`.